# dynamoDB can't insert new item

Tags: swift, amazon-dynamodb

I am currently using DynamoDB. I found out that I can't add new item to database table. It just fill the new information to one existing object stored in the database table. Here is the code

```
let customer: Customers = Customers()

customer._userId = AWSIdentityManager.default().identityId!
customer._firstName = "Chen1"
customer._lastName = "DSA"
customer._address = ["A303,Sa 41-45 Belmore st,ryde"]
customer._email = ["chenhoaSasanglei3215@gmail.com"]
customer._mobile = ["04246saSa41108"]
customer._chineseIDNumber = ["4405saSasaS20195013"]
customer._fullName = "H"

//Save a new item
dynamoDbObjectMapper.save(customer).continueWith(block: { (task:AWSTask<AnyObject>!) -> Any? in
    if let error = task.error as? NSError {
        print("The request failed. Error: \(error)")
    } else {
        print("item saved",task)
    }
    return nil
})
```

Comment: Since you said that it overwrites the existing object, the primary key value which you are going to insert seems already available. Just for try, Can u give a random but different value in the primary key and insert?

Comment: The primary key is available actually. But we are allowed to set up a table using the same primary key, do we?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I forgot to set up a sort key . Problem solve thanks

Comment: Glad u solved, Just for understanding the issue, What was your sort key, u set up?